# Can't build project with Android Studio 3.0 + DataBinding + Kotlin

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I have a huge project with databinding, kotlin, dagger. I spent a few days trying to build it using several stackoverflow's solutions and decided to ask it personally.

I assume some of third party libraries uses databinding because adding this line doesn't help.

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0'
```

Android Studio says:

> 'androidProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0'.

**What I've tried and it didn't help:**

```
   kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

in local.properties: `kotlin.incremental=false`

another SO solution **didn't help**:

```
kapt ('com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
```

my build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'blockcanaryex'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

def props = new Properties()
file("newrelic.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
            exec {
                commandLine "git", "symbolic-ref", "--short", "HEAD"
                standardOutput = stdout
            }
            def branch = stdout.toString().trim()
            branch = "branch.$branch"

            if (project.hasProperty("buildNumber")) {
                def buildNumber = project.property("buildNumber")
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + branch + "-" + versionName + "." + versionCode + "." + buildNumber + ".apk"))
            } else {
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + branch + "-" + versionName + "." + versionCode + ".apk"))
            }
        }
    }

    def version = "4.15"

    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN", "\"" + props.getProperty("token") + "\""
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionName version

        versionCode 260

        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }



    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("xxx")
            storePassword "xxx"
            keyAlias "xxx"
            keyPassword "xxx"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            versionNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "prod","stag"

    productFlavors {



        production {
            dimension "prod"
        }

        staging {
            dimension "stag"
            applicationId "app.id"
            versionName(version + ".staging")
        }

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude '.readme'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}


repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://bitbucket.org/gryphteam/maven/raw/release' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}


def supportVersion = "26.1.0"
def playServicesVersion = "11.6.0"
def retrofitVersion = "2.3.0"

dependencies {


    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    implementation('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0'


    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$playServicesVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    implementation files('libs/comscore.jar')
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
    implementation 'org.jboss.netty:netty:3.2.10.Final'

    //Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:rules:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'app-compat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'

    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportVersion"
    implementation project(':eventsource_android-release')
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.letv.sarrsdesktop:BlockCanaryExJRT:0.9.5.3'
    releaseImplementation 'com.letv.sarrsdesktop:BlockCanaryExJRTNoOp:0.9.5.3'
    testImplementation 'com.letv.sarrsdesktop:BlockCanaryExJRTNoOp:0.9.5.3'


    implementation 'me.mvdw.recyclerviewmergeadapter:recyclerviewmergeadapter:2.0.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ReactiveX:RxKotlin:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.gojuno.koptional:koptional-rxjava2-extensions:1.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.14.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: You did `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @david.mihola, I added my build.gradle, yes it's there.

Comment: I'm getting the same "androidProcessor..." complaint in my project while it still builds and works fine. Are you sure that is the right real reason why build fails?

Comment: try using  dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }  i am using all things in my project like dagger realm and its working fine

Comment: @SamiRajala, yes, I'm sure build fails because of that.

Comment: @pankajyadav, man, seriously? Look at the question, there is attached whole listing of build.gradle file.

Comment: what is gradle version for this project , can you please check the gradle version you are using for you project level build.gradle

Comment: Refer this might be help you [Link 1](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live-kotlin/todoapp/build.gradle) and [Link 2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live-kotlin/todoapp/app/build.gradle)

Comment: The google sample is generating the same warning

Comment: I found two entries in the Google issue tracker which deal with the _annotationProcessor_ warning: [Issue 77234253](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77234253) and [issue 65357518](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65357518).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just tried with similar `build.gradle` settings in a new and fresh kotlin project and it builds. Unfortunately I couldn't use all your libs and your exact setting but maybe it's just a matter of order. Here is my

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nice.fontaine.kottest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    implementation('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0'

    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.6.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0"

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
    implementation 'org.jboss.netty:netty:3.2.10.Final'

    //Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:rules:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'app-compat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations:22.2.1'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'

    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0"
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.letv.sarrsdesktop:BlockCanaryExJRT:0.9.5.3'
    releaseImplementation 'com.letv.sarrsdesktop:BlockCanaryExJRTNoOp:0.9.5.3'
    testImplementation 'com.letv.sarrsdesktop:BlockCanaryExJRTNoOp:0.9.5.3'

    implementation 'me.mvdw.recyclerviewmergeadapter:recyclerviewmergeadapter:2.0.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.gojuno.koptional:koptional-rxjava2-extensions:1.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.14.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
}
```

At least I can verify with this test that

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0'
```

is working for me. Maybe try it in a new project too and check if this works and then slowly apply your other libs one by one. Hope that gets you on track!

Comment: I don't know exactly why it helped, because I tried same config, but now I wrote '3.0.1' ver. of plugin and databinding compiler. Maybe they fixed some issues in the new plugin, anyway, thanks, it works.

Comment: The problem comes from `dataBinding {enabled = true}`, so for sure, you don't have any problem as you're not using it. But it's required to use Data Binding

Answer (score -8):

Just remove the Kotlin library. Android Stidio 3.0 supports it by default.

Comment: Do you mean this line `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"` ?

Comment: I've tried it, doesn't help, build fails with same message

Comment: It won't compile without the library. It's like saying `remove the AppCompat library to use the AppCompatActivity properly`